# Highcharts : setData causes unwanted flashing on redraw()

Tags: highcharts

I update the chart dynamically every two seconds to keep the chart up to date. This update causes the chart to flash repeatedly. A short video can be found on YouTube: https://youtu.be/bP8HYQBldMc

I have disbaled all animation in an effort to prevent any movement of the line but it semms to make no difference.

The code is in typescript (anguar2 project) but the Highcharts Object is pure JS :

```
    this.chart["series"][0].setData(bellChart.productionData, false);
    this.chart["xAxis"][0].setExtremes(bellChart.from, bellChart.until, false, false);
    this.chart.redraw(false);
```

.

Chart options :

```
{
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                skipClone: true
            },
            title: {text: ''},
            series: [{}],
            credits: {enabled: false},
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 14400 * 1000,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                lineColor: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                tickColor: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                        fontSize: HighchartsThemes.FONT_SIZE
                    },
                },
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    millisecond: '%H',
                    second: '%H',
                    minute: '%H',
                    hour: '%H',
                    day: '%H',
                    month: '%H',
                    year: '%H'
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickInterval: 25,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickLength: 5,
                title: {
                    text: null,
                    reserveSpace: false
                },
                gridLineColor: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                gridLineDashStyle: "dash",
                lineColor: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                tickColor: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value + " %";
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                        fontSize: HighchartsThemes.FONT_SIZE
                    },
                },
            },
            legend: {
                borderColor: HighchartsThemes.LINE_COLOR,
                floating: true,
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            },
            tooltip: {enabled: false},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    animation: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false,
                    marker: {enabled: false}
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: @ewolden, sorry updated

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue using random data but flickering doesn't occur: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/z7rtuoo2/ Please provide some live working example that reproduces this issue.